# Q: Insurance company related probability problem

Tags: probability

I came across this problem:

An insurance agent offers an insurance policy to $2n$ costumers. Each costumer accepts the offer with probability $0<\alpha<1$ and rejects it with probability $1-\alpha$. A costumer who accepted the offer choose randomly one of $3n$ service centers of the insurance company. All the decisions of the costumers are independent. Assuming that $n$ is very large, what approximately is the probability that more than 2 costumers chose a given service center?

I guess the assumption is a hint to use the binomial distribution for the number of costumers who chose a given service center, and then approximate it using the Poisson distribution.

I began by writing $X_i\sim Bin(N,\frac{1}{3n})$, where $X_i$ is the number of costumers who chose service center number $i$, but couldn't figure out how to find the number of costumers $N$ who accepted the agent's offer, since it is itself a random variable.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You could work out the probability *conditional* on $N$ taking a particular value $k$ and then convolute that probability (which has a parameter $k$) with the distribution of $N$ itself.